# Change environment variable RUN TIME

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I change the environment variable RUN TIME?
Using Login PAGE I am selecting Development or Production.
Based on that **I have to use my ConnectionString device specifically**.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"PROJECTNAME_Development": "SERVER_DETAILS",
"PROJECTNAME_Production": "SERVER_DETAILS",
}
```

Here are my LoginServices.CS file

```
public class LoginService: ILoginService
{
        private readonly string _connectionString = string.Empty;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
}
public LoginService (IConfiguration configuration)
{
        _configuration = configuration;
        //If ADMIN SELECT Development
        _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("PROJECTNAME_Development");
        //If ADMIN SELECT Production
        _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("PROJECTNAME_Production");
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I tried this code. **It works fine but** is there any other way like at one location I make a change and Environment Variable value gets updated.

My Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    model.DevelopmentServer = "Development";
                    // model.DevelopmentServer = "Production";
                    ...
                     var Result = ILoginService.AdminLogin(model);
```

```
 public LoginService(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<ConnectionStringDetails> connectionStrings)
        {
            _proDBCon = connectionStrings.Value.PROJECTNAME_Development;
            _proDBConProduction = connectionStrings.Value.PROJECTNAME_Production;
        }
```

In the same file LoginService.cs File

```
public LoginInfo AdminLogin(LoginModel model)
{
 if (model.DevelopmentServer == "Development") {
                _connectionString = _proDBCon;
            }
            else {
                _connectionString = _proDBConProduction;
            }
}
```

Comment: You can change env variables via ```System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("name", "value")```

Comment: so  the comment line in code says if admin select development, and if admin select production, what does that mean? so you want to let admin to be able to switch connection string in running time?

Comment: you can change configuration at run time like this:

```Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:Default"] = "Hello";```   

i hope this link help you: https://enlabsoftware.com/development/dotnet-core-environment-how-config-examples.html

Comment: @Maytham I want to fire the If condition Here... Like at RUN TIME from LOGIN PAGE IF ADMIN SELECT the Development from the DROPDOWN menu then use `PROJECTNAME_Development` connection string and if `Production` then selects `PROJECTNAME_Production` connection string.

Comment: how the system will know if you are admin if you are not connected yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to switch between two databases from UI at any cost, you won't be able to complete it entirely using containers/injections. You have to use the value passed from UI to determine which database connection string should be used.

```
public class LoginService {
   // ...
   private string GetConnectionString(string connectionStringNameFromUi){
       return _configuration.GetConnectionString
   }
}
```

Meanwhile, I would consider deploying two separate instances of an application, one configured for dev and another for prod. In such way, you would get more out of the box (injections container and environment configuration).

Comment: it is never really a good idea to make an App able to switch between different environments in the same session. If any form of caching is implemented those caches will often have to be cleared, which might involve a lot of indirect code being directly manipulated. It is better long term to deploy two separate instances as @karlis has suggested.

Comment: Updated the question and added new code after `Update 1`. It works fine but still needs your help.